# Android - Buttons Hidden by the Android Interface

Tags: android

It displays well on the preview however when I run, the last button is hidden by the interface. How can i solve this problem?

**EDIT:** Now that I think about it I think it's the TitleBar size. How can I solve this?

[image]

XML CODE:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.ContactUsFragment"
android:background="@color/AMOB_gray">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="AMOB Headquarters"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Rua Padre Domingos Joaquim Pereira,1249"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="4760-563 Louro"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/AMOB_gray"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Vila Nova de Famalicão, Portugal"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Phone: (+351) 252 330 900"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Fax: (+351) 252 376 887"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="E-mail: comercial@amob.pt"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="GPS: 41º 26'.16''N / 8º32'31.89''W"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gps_amob"
        android:id="@+id/gps_map"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_emailUs"
        android:background="@drawable/round_buttons"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Email us">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_callUs"
        android:background="@drawable/round_buttons_green"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Call Us">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: put your FrameLayout in a ScrollView

Comment: You need ScrollView

Comment: Dont use LinearLayout
If u r using LinearLAyout, make it a child of ScrollView
or
Use RelativeLayout with gravity:bottom, Put 2 buttons first, Put the map container layout after in xml above those buttons will solve your issue.

Comment: DEsign from bottom to top, that will be easy for you.

Comment: still happens the same https://i.gyazo.com/0f5ca1bec604b6fdea56a323ef7c3b04.png

Answer (score 0):

there is no actionbar in preview, but in emulator you're getting actionbar, thats why last button in getting hidden,i think check the theme for that particular layout in manifest file. and ya if u want actionbar the you need to add scrollview

Comment: but now u must be able to scroll through all your button.If you want all the button to be visible in screen without scroll. you will have to manually adjust by giving hard coded height to all the widgets which is wrong process.

Comment: I'm not. I scroll all the way to the bottom and the android interface still hiding the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
Action bar is causing problem as in preview there is no Action bar..check this layout.

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.ContactUsFragment"
    android:background="@color/AMOB_gray">
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillviewport="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="AMOB Headquarters"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="Rua Padre Domingos Joaquim Pereira,1249"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="4760-563 Louro"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@color/AMOB_gray"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="Vila Nova de Famalicão, Portugal"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="Phone: (+351) 252 330 900"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="Fax: (+351) 252 376 887"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="E-mail: comercial@amob.pt"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="GPS: 41º 26'.16''N / 8º32'31.89''W"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/gps_amob"
            android:id="@+id/gps_map"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btn_emailUs"
            android:background="@drawable/round_buttons"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Email us">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btn_callUs"
            android:background="@drawable/round_buttons_green"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Call Us">
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your UI is too big for the device to render, wrap your layout in a scrollview to enable vertical scrolling of the UI on devices that cannot display the entire UI at once:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

//Put your layout here

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Did you try scrolling down the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Put **ScrollView** in your **XML** and also add a **margin Bottom** on your Buttons

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.tiagosilva.amob_android.ContactUsFragment"
    android:background="@color/AMOB_gray">
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillviewport="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="AMOB Headquarters"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="Rua Padre Domingos Joaquim Pereira,1249"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="4760-563 Louro"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@color/AMOB_gray"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="Vila Nova de Famalicão, Portugal"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="Phone: (+351) 252 330 900"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="Fax: (+351) 252 376 887"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="E-mail: comercial@amob.pt"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="GPS: 41º 26'.16''N / 8º32'31.89''W"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/gps_amob"
            android:id="@+id/gps_map"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btn_emailUs"
            android:background="@drawable/round_buttons"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Email us">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btn_callUs"
            android:background="@drawable/round_buttons_green"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Call Us">
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
```